# Puppeteer: How to detect url of newly opened tab before http redirect

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm writing some integration tests.

My web app opens a new tab/window when a button is clicked (via `window.open()`). The URL of the new tab http redirects once to a final url. I'd like to be able to detect what the *first* URL was (IE. the url passed to `window.open()`) before landing on the final page.

I understand there is a [`request.redirectChain()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v1.10.0/docs/api.md#requestredirectchain) API, which would (in theory) give me the data I need, although I have no idea how to get a reference to the initial request invoked by `window.open()` API.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this chain have а race condition, but you can try:

[Browser event `'targetcreated'`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v1.10.0/docs/api.md#event-targetcreated) ->
[`target.page()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v1.10.0/docs/api.md#targetpage) ->
[Page event `'request'`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v1.10.0/docs/api.md#event-request).